# DOM or SAX for serialization

Tags: c++, xml-serialization

I'm creating a C++ server and a client in Java. For exchaning data structures between them, I planned to use XML using xerces-c as this is available on both sides. As I have only a VERY rudimentary understanding of XML engines, I was googling to find out what I need.

So when receiving an XML on either side, I would use the SAX parser. However if I understood this right, then I can not use this to serialize an object into XML, so I would have to use DOM when I want to send the data, right?

Now I at least understand a little bit better the difference between SAX and DOM, so I figured that using SAX is easier, but it can not be used for creating an XML, only for reading it.

Now my questions, is it a good idea to use both, or shall I rather stick to DOM in this case? The actual processing should be rather simple. When an object should be transfered it should copy it's data into the XML which gets transfered. So I don't need to do queries except when deserializing.

Comment: This probably belongs on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you might want to have a look into **Apache Swift**, which is a perfect framework to generate a C++ Server with a Java client to exchange data structures between these languages. You can learn swift and generate your client and server source codes automatically in around 2 hours. Check the example at http://thrift.apache.org/

To your question. I think you understand DOM and SAX correctly.

**DOM:** Reads the entire XML document at  once and puts it into an object (in the RAM). This does not work very very large documents, which don't fit into the RAM.

**SAX:** This reads the XML document line by line and the parser that you develop, decides line by  line what to do.

If  you have an existing object, it is usually straight forward to generate an  XML out of it. You can use the Simple XML Framework (http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to serialize and deserialize your Java objects.

I think you should read and write as much as possible with the **DOM** strategy, because it is easier and will cause you less trouble, since you are exchanging and serializing objects. Use SAX only if you have very large files (or many very small files at the same time) in the RAM.